# Google Colab Disk space vs Google Drive disk space

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colab to do some machine learning project. I've mounted my drive, activated the GPU, purchased extra storage space from google drive, and have over 100Gb of free space on google drive, but the "drive" monitor in my Colab notebook says that the drive is filling up. Screen shots of my Colab notbook and Google Drive storage below.

[image]

[image]

Why does the notebook show that the drive is filling up? I've refreshed my google drive several times to make sure that the storage space that's showing is accurate.

Comment: Please update your post to clarify that you have **purchased** extra space in your Google Drive.

Comment: Similar question in [Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/34430621/why-does-google-drive-show-a-different-size-when-mounted-in-colab?hl=en) remains unanswered since March 2020.

Answer (score 7):

The Google Drive storage and Google Colab disk space are different.

Google drive storage is the space given in the google cloud. whereas the colab disk space is the amount of storage in the machine alloted to you at that time. You can increase the storage by changing the runtime.

A machine with GPU has more memory and diskspace than a runtime with cpu only.
Similarly if you want more, you can change the runtime to a TPU machine.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "changing runtime"? Under the Runtime dropdown menu, I see "change runtime type", but this just sets my version of Python and whether or not I have an accelerator activated. I'm considering doing the "factory reset runtime" option?

Comment: Yes. Change Runtime Type. You have to select a hardware accelerator. GPU or TPU. Depending on which machine you want. Mark as Answer if I helped

Comment: Hmm, as i mentioned in my original post, i've already selected and activated a GPU. So i'm still not sure what to do here. I still can't seem to clear or significantly reduce the occupied space on the Colab disk even after stoping the runtime and closing the notebook.

Comment: Change to TPU and check

Comment: Although not very clear in the question itself, it is apparent from the 1st screenshot that OP has purchased extra storage space in Google Drive (200 GB), and they have in turn *mounted* Google Drive in Colab. The question in essence is about the discrepancy in storage between the two screenshots, and your answer, although correct as a very general description, is out of context here.

Comment: The google drive storage mounted or not, will not affect the colab storage. The answer is very clear. Colab is showing the free space in the runtime machine alloted to the user. It doesn't include the google drive space and won't show up. If you are mounting drive space, make sure you keep the data in drive itself and not copied to the machine.

Comment: What OP asks is that, although, they have purchased extra Drive space, and they have mounted this Drive to Colab, they cannot access this extra space in the Drive itself through Colab.

Comment: I've spent a week on this, including ~1 hour chatting with Google support. Even the GPU/CPU distinction you make does not necessarily work always like that - I get *less* storage with GPU than with CPU/TPU (depends on the region, maybe?). You can always use the extra storage of GD for *reading* and accessing stuff that is already there, but not for writing dynamically during code execution. Such stuff (and research) is expected in a decent answer.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're seeing your colab drive space fill as you read or write to your mounted Google Drive is because colab will cache contents from Google Drive on its own local storage.

Cached items that aren't in use will be evicted as the colab drive fills, but often the reason you're mounting Google Drive is because you want to have more files in use -- though because of the file caching, you'll pretty much be out of luck there.

Answer (score 0):

Google drive storage and google colab disk are different. Google drive storage is object storage system while google colab disk is a File system that you use during the colab runtime(mostly a SSD, or a HDD). Both are different and have different usage (read [here](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/data-storage/file-block-object-storage) for more).

The problem you are facing is the shortage of SSD disk during the runtime. Google colab has no option to increase this. You need to shift to [cloud notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks) to increase the size of the runtime SSD.

Answer (score 0):

See my NCDU screenshot below, made while using my Colab Pro subscription to try and convert the 150GB Llama-2 70B model to GGML format.

Although I am working on the data directly on the mounted Google Drive (of which I have 2TB, vs the 200GB of free space on the Colab Pro local storage), what you're seeing in NCDU is that all the input files (`d5*` in the cache, but a bunch of `.pth` files on the mounted filesystem) AND output file (`d10` in the cache, but a single `.bin` file on the mounted filesystem) are being cached in `/root/.config/Google/DriveFS`.

They will remain there taking up space, until they are not used by any processes anymore. Once your processing is complete, you'll see the `drive` process taking up cpu cycles in `top` until it finishes writing everything to your Google Drive and finally deletes the cache.

This is the reason why you see your disk usage going up even when you're working directly on the Google Drive mount.

I have not yet been able to find a work-around for this regrettable behaviour. In this specific case, being able to disable the cache would have been good, because the conversion process is read-once write-once.

[image: ncdu screenshot showing colab / drive mount cache behaviour]

Comment: If someone was motivated enough, they could probably write a FUSE filesystem in Python that used many small files on Google Drive as a type of block storage.  This way blocks that aren't in current use could be evicted.  Of course, unless there's a similar existing project that could be adapted, it sounds like a lot of work -- and would not be very performant. And then of course you won't have direct access to the files stored in the filesystem outside of the colab.